# JQuery UI Loaded Event?

Tags: jquery, onload-event

Is there anyway to not only detect that the jquery UI loaded but also fire an event when it does? Right now I have code wrapped in a $(document).ready() function but sometimes the UI code errors out because the UI library did not fully load (everything is loading in the correct order). The code works 99% of the time but about 1% of the users get a javascript error related to the UI not loading.

Something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.ui.ready(function() { ....
```

Is anything like this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: did you put your script inclusion on the head of the document ?

Comment: Make sure your jQuery code is after the reference to jQueryUI. Your code should not execute until jQueryUI is loaded.

Comment: Everything is included in the head, jquery is loaded prior to jquery UI. The code works perfect 99% of the time, it had something to do with latency issues or browser loading speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to load your plugin like jQuery-ui and other with getcript and hold the ready function(s) before the script is fully loaded

```
// Hold the ready function(s)
$.holdReady(true);

// Retrieve the script and unlock the ready function(s) when the script is loaded
$.getScript("myplugin.js", function() {
    $.holdReady(false);
});
```

Keeping you ready function(s) simple

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // your code here

});
```

Comment: Oh good idea I was not aware of that option. I think that should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem in the past.  Use this:

```
if (typeof jQuery.ui != 'undefined') {
  //do something
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will only check procedurally, once the check has passed it doesn't return to try again. That's what I need because if it is undefined I need to to be called when it does get defined.